# The "^" sign over the "=" sign

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators

I want to have the "^" sign over the "=" sign.

I have tried `\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{^}{=}}`, `\newcommand{\defeq}{\stackrel{\text{^}}{=}}`, `\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\^}{=}}` and different combinations of these, but none have worked yet. 
Also, I would like my command only to work in math mode (in the `{$$}`, `\begin{equation}`, and such environments). I do not want it to work in textmode, so the output of `\defeq , {$\defeq$}` should be `, ^=` (but the ^ over the =).

Comment: Yes @campa. However, that post did not include how to make the command exclusively work in math mode. So it is not entirely a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that last sentence (close vote retracted). But why would you want that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `\newcommand{\defeq}{\mathrel{\hat=}}`.

Comment: Right! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: \newcommand{\defeq}{\hat{=}} works fine. (I use the packages `mathtools` and `amssymb` (amsmath is included in mathtools). Thank you.

Comment: But you did not explain how to only make it work in math mode.